# algorithm for finding the radius of a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

> The eccentricity of a vertex v is the length of the shortest path from that vertex to the furthest vertex from v in an undirected graph. The diameter of an undirected graph is the maximum eccentricity of any vertex. The radius of an undirected graph is the smallest eccentricity of any vertex. A center is a vertex whose eccentricity is the radius. Assuming a connected, unweighted, undirected graph G, give an algorithm to compute the radius of G.

I am using the definitions given above to compute a radius for a connected, unweighted, undirected graph.  So far, my algorithm consists of this:

1. For each vertex $v$ in graph$ $G, use Bellman-Ford to find the furthest vertex from $v$ (longest of the shortests paths found).
2. record the path $s_0,s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$ for vertexes $1,2,3,\ldots,n$.

   Note: the order of the chosen vertexes is arbitrary, as long as all vertexes are analyzed once and only once.
3. Compare all paths $s_0,s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$ and return the shortest path in the set of recorded paths.

My question is if this algorithm works, or if it doesn't, how I can modify it to fix it or make it better.  I know that Bellman-Ford computes the shortest path to every vertex in the graph so doing this for every vertex in the graph would be pretty exhaustive, perhaps even unnecessary.

Comment: I have seen this question earlier and it was closed or I mess something?

Comment: Please don't [delete your question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74720/755) and then re-post it without addressing the feedback you've received.  Instead, it is better to edit the question to address the feedback you've received about how to improve the question.  Deleting and re-posting your question can lead to your account being [banned from asking further questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/160917).

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Did you try proving  your algorithm correct?  Did you try testing it on a million randomly generated graphs?  We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions.  It's better to ask a conceptual question that will be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing the philosophy of stack overflow because I'm relatively new to it, but my question was marked down -2 because I did not include enough detail as to what I needed help with, I fixed this by including the algorithm I came up with and simply asked if the concept would work (i dont need code, just the initial concept), and now two people have not tried answering but instead told me how I asked the question wrong. I'm not stuck I just don't know how to prove this works or if there is a better way to go about solving this.

Comment: Am I wrong by making a new question on the basis of nobody giving attention to down-voted questions ?